# WPF ContextMenu item style not applied in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF application with a context menu based on MVVM. The context menu items can be added dynamically via the corresponding view model. My view looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="MyItemStyle">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            </Style>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MyItemContainer" 
                                      DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/WpfApp11;component/Resources/Images.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3">
        <Grid>
            <Button Width="100" Height="30">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MeasurementContextMenu}" 
                                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemContainer}"/>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

The view model looks like this:

```
public class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MainModel()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        var first = new MenuItemViewModel("Just a test");
        var second = new MenuItemViewModel("Second");
        first.MenuItems.Add(second);
        MeasurementContextMenu.Add(first);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MeasurementContextMenu { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the view model for the menu items:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields

    private string _header;

    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors

    public MenuItemViewModel(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }

    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties

    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return _header;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_header != value)
            {
                _header = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> MenuItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion Properties
}
```

So the hierarchical stuff works as expected, but the applied style doesn't work. So the items appear but without any text. It seems this property doesn't have any impact

```
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}"
```

How can the style be applied in this case?

Comment: Your `ItemTemplate` overrides `ItemContainerStyle`. Set `Header` binding in template or attach style to `ItemTemplate` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MeasurementContextMenu}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemContainer}"/>
```

...and put a `TextBlock` that binds to `Header` in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MyItemContainer" 
                          DataType="{x:Type local:MenuItemViewModel}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: That would be OK when there is only a header text. But later on I want to add other things like Icon, IsCheckable, IsChecked etc. Therfore I do not want to use the TextBlock in the template... In addition it does not explain while the style is not applied when I use the key "MyItemStyle". When I define a style without key it seems to work - but still do not understand why..

Comment: @FranzGsell: Then you should simply replace the `TextBlock` with a `Panel`. The solution to your issue is still the same. Did you really downvote this answer...?

Comment: So what do you mean with replace TextBlock with Panel? Do you mean I should add a panel with corresponding controls to handle IsCheck, IsCheckable, Icon etc. by myself? And yes I downvoted the answer because it does not really answer the question: "Why is the ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyItemStyle}"  not applied? Your solution seems more like a workaround...